# C++ STD Thread Pool

Tags: c++, multithreading, reinventing-the-wheel

I wanted to try implementing my own version of a C++ Thread Pool (I know there are lots of them..).

I was hoping that someone could tell if I did it okay.

Tasker.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <shared_mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

#include "../Worker/Worker.h"

class Tasker
{

public:

    //  Default Tasker Constructor.
    Tasker(const unsigned int & newTaskerThreadCount)
    {
        //  Construct the Vector of Threads. By default, each of these will not have any thread associated.
        mTaskerThreads = std::vector<std::thread>(newTaskerThreadCount);
    }


    //  Default Tasker Destructor, waits for all the workers to complete.
    virtual ~Tasker()
    {
        end();
    }


    //  Add Worker to the List of Workers to Execute.
    inline virtual void addWorker(std::shared_ptr<Worker> newWorker)
    {
        //  Create a unique lock.
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lockWorkers(mWorkersMutex);

        //  Add a worker.
        mWorkers.push(newWorker);

        //  Release the lock.
        lockWorkers.release();

        //  Notify all waiting threads.
        mWorkersCB.notify_all();
    }


    //  Begin executing any workers in the queue.
    inline virtual void begin()
    {
        //  
        mIsActive = true;

        //  Create all the Threads.
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mTaskerThreads.size(); i++)
        {
            mTaskerThreads[i] = std::thread(&Tasker::executeWorker, this);
        }
    }


    //  End the execution, waiting for all the workers in the queue to complete.
    inline virtual void end()
    {
        //  
        mIsEnd = true;

        //  Create a unique lock.
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lockWorkers(mWorkersMutex);

        //  Wait forever.
        while (true)
        {
            //  Lock the Workers.
            if (!lockWorkers.owns_lock())
            {
                lockWorkers.lock();
            }

            //  Check if all the work is finished.
            if (mWorkers.size() == 0)
            {
                //  Wait for all the threads to finish.
                for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mTaskerThreads.size(); i++)
                {
                    //  Wait for a thread to finish.
                    mTaskerThreads[i].join();
                }
            }

            //  Unlock the Workers Mutex.
            lockWorkers.release();
        }

        //  No longer active.
        mIsActive = false;

        //  No longer end.
        mIsEnd = false;
    }





private:

    //  Execute the Work on a Thread.
    inline virtual void executeWorker()
    {
        //  Create a unique lock.
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lockWorkers(mWorkersMutex);

        //  
        while (true)
        {
            //  Lock the Workers.
            if (!lockWorkers.owns_lock())
            {
                lockWorkers.lock();
            }

            //  Check if we have any work.
            if (mWorkers.size() > 0)
            {
                //  Get the first available work.
                std::shared_ptr<Worker> worker = mWorkers.front();

                //  Remove it from the queue.
                mWorkers.pop();

                //  Release the lock.
                lockWorkers.release();

                //  Execute the Work.
                if (worker != nullptr)
                {
                    worker->executeWork();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //  
                if (mIsEnd)
                {
                    //  Release the lock.
                    lockWorkers.release();

                    //  Break.
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    //  Release the lock and wait.
                    mWorkersCB.wait(lockWorkers);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    //  The Vector of Tasker Threads.
    std::vector<std::thread> mTaskerThreads;

    //  The Mutex for the Vector of Workers.
    std::mutex mWorkersMutex;

    //  The Vector of Work Assignments.
    std::queue<std::shared_ptr<Worker>> mWorkers;

    //  Whether or not the Tasker is active.
    std::atomic_bool mIsActive = false;

    //  Whether or not the Tasker is ending.
    std::atomic_bool mIsEnd = false;

    //  Condition Variable the Workers wait on.
    std::condition_variable mWorkersCB;

};
```

Worker.h:

```
#pragma once

class Worker
{

public:

    //  Default Worker Constructor.
    Worker() = default;

    //  Default Worker Destructor.
    virtual ~Worker() = default;

    //  Execute the Work. 
    virtual void executeWork() = 0;


private:


};
```

Comment: It would be great if it would issue `std::future`, so that it would be useful with other standard library components.

Comment: mWorkersCB.wait - I do not see how you force the threads exit this wait when you start destructing  your object...

Comment: If you know there are lots of them, you should also include your design considerations and explanation of what you did different from existing pools and why (at least for a one or two).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Logic error: end() never ends**

`end()` needs to finish somehow.

If `end()` was only ever called in the destructor, you could then guarantee that no one else is interacting with the object at that point. It would then simply be:

```
for (auto& thread : mTaskerThreads)
{
  //  Wait for a thread to finish.
  thread.join();
}
```

**Use initializer lists**

Tasker's constructor should look like this:

```
Tasker(const unsigned int & newTaskerThreadCount)
  : mTaskerThreads(newTaskerThreadCount) {}
```

Otherwise, your vector gets set to the default state, then it gets stomped by a new vector. By initializing it in the list, it goes straight to the final state.

**inline is implicit for functions defined inside of a class' declaration**

```
inline virtual void addWorker(std::shared_ptr<Worker> newWorker) {...}
^^^^^^
redundant
```

**Use range-based for unless you have a reason not to**

It's a lot cleaner and, more importantly, less error-prone.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mTaskerThreads.size(); i++)
//vs
for(auto& thread : mTaskerThreads) {...}
```

**use empty() instead of comparing the size of a vector to 0**

```
if (mWorkers.size() == 0)
//vs
if (mWorkers.empty())
```

**So many virtual functions**

Only functions that are meant to be overloaded should be virtual. From what I can tell, this is not the case for any of the functions in `Tasker`. Get rid of the virtual.

**Pass small types by value**

`const type &` can sometimes provide great savings when passing large structs around, but for the core types, you are really hamstringing the compiler.

```
Tasker(const unsigned int& newTaskerThreadCount);
//vs
Tasker(unsigned int newTaskerThreadCount);
```

**Explicit begin() and end() creates a very wide invariant**

I would get rid of the `begin()` and `end()` functions, and just implement them at construction/destruction, that will simplify the logic a lot (getting rid of mActive and mEnded altogether, as well as making cleanup a lot simpler). Telling users of the class to manage that cycle through lifetime and scoping is absolutely fine.

**Worker() = default; is rundundant**

If you don't add any other constructor, this is implicitely done for you.

**prefer header guards to #pragma once**

While widely supported, `#pragma once` is not part of the language. If you are making a generic, portable, tool, you should avoid it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was really helpful. I'll fix those issues!